# CSS Content set left or right (Image and text) using Div element

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height:315px;
}
.wrapper.image{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 259px;
}
.wrapper.text{

}
.left{
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image left"><img src="img.jpg"></div>
    <div class="text left">Text</div>
</div>
```

I want the image positioned at the bottom of the wrapper div, but then my text doesn't recognize the image div as a element and the text div is placed on top of the image div.
I could put in position absolute for the text as well, but seems like too much hard-coding.
Is there another way to make sure these two divs recognize (a better word for this?) each other?

I want this design:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/enNAo.jpg
In this example I'm showing 2 rows.

Comment: Still not understand what you want from your existing design?

Comment: I want the img on the bottom, and the text on the right of the img. and if the screen size changes, i want it to readjust the left/right margin. with position: absolute, I can't do that.

Comment: This is still very unclear. What do you want in what order, and at what screen sizes - roughly.

Comment: Putting any height at all is too much hard coding.

Comment: does this help? http://i.imgur.com/iMjTg9z.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[A fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c2KZs/)

This way the content can decide the height and it's responsive

#### edit:

here is another fiddle that uses inline-block - but you'll have to really understand positioning to have it be useful http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/62pU3/

/* vertical center needs, (more that one thing... display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle - on all things involved... keep in mind they are aligning to each other --- not their parent */

(original)

### HTML

```
<div class="block">

    <div class="image-w">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="text-w">
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>

</div> <!-- .block -->
```

### CSS

```
.block {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;

    /* this should be a clear fix - or floated instead - because now that the divs inside are floated, it no longer understands how they work unless clear fixed, or (floated itself ) */ 
    overflow: hidden; /* temp replacement for clear fix */
    /* float: left; */
}

.image-w img { /* image fills wrapper | decide size with wrapper */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.block .image-w {
    float: left;
}

.block .text-w {
    float: left;
}

/* @media rule "break-point" */
@media (min-width: 40em) {

    .block {
        padding-top: 2em; /* arbitrary space */
    }

    .block .image-w {
        max-width: 15em;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }

    /* i would usually use nth-of-type(even) {} */
    .oposite-block .image-w {
        float: right;
    }

    .block .text-w {
        float: none;
        max-width: 50em;
    }

} /* end breakpoint */
```

Comment: the problem with this: if the text is long, it spills to the image's side, I did not want it to spill over there. I suppose I'd have to use the media breakpoint...what do you mean "i would usually use nth of type"?

Comment: There are probably 10 ways to do this well, but I can't really spend any more time guessing at your constraints. Here is one last fiddle with floats. Try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/kbv3d/  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your image and text inside one `div` and apply position: absolute.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7nUT/2/)

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height:315px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
} 


.left {
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7nUT/4/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://podcast.iu.edu/upload/IUSEUITS/images/300x300.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
        </div>   
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid #f15a27;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
} 
img{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.text {
    margin:16px 10px 0 0;
    float:right;
}
```